# How to get the last value of an element in a List in Java?

Tags: java, list

Is it possible to get the last value of an element inside a list with many different values?

```
List<EventDTO> eventDto = new ArrayList<>();
```

Inside this list there are three elements: `id(Integer)`, `name(String)`, and `lastStatus(String)`

I'm trying to compare a String to see if it's equal to the last value stored in the element `lastStatus` inside the list. As the event is updated, many values are stored in said element. I'm trying to get the last one stored.

```
String originalStatus = 'Pending';
```

How can I access the list, find the element `lastStatus`, and see if the last value stored inside of it equals to `originalStatus` ?

Comment: Assuming you have getters for your fields, something like : `eventDto.get(eventDto.size() - 1).getLastStatus().equals(originalStatus);`

Answer (score 1):

In accordance to **Java 8** here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html, you could use the function

`E get(int index)`

to access last element in a list. It returns the element at the specified position in this list.

Example: `eventDto.get(eventDto.size() -1 )`

while using the function

`int size()`

to get the last index of the list.

For comparison, you can use the function
`boolean equals(Object o)` of **String** class on the the adequate attribut.

Comment: I'm not trying to get the last element in a list, but the last value of a certain element (not necessarily the last one)

Comment: Did you mean "most recent" value?